# How to add another ImageView over an existing ImageView dynamically?

Tags: android, xml, imageview

I know similar questions have been asked before but I think my case is different.
So I'm trying to make a playlist using a RecyclerView and when a song is selected I want the circular image which holds the Image for the song to change to a tick sign while the original image can be seen faded in the background. I have my tick image ready.[image]

How can I add this image over my existing ImageView dynamically? The putting one image in the background method is not a solution for me because the music image file is loaded dynamically from Realm and thus can't be the background.

The XML code for my RecyclerView items is below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="30dp"
>

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
android:layout_width="120dp"
android:layout_height="120dp"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:transitionName="albumArt"
android:id="@+id/album_art"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
android:src="@color/colorPrimary"/>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
     android:id="@+id/data"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
      android:textColor="#ffffff"
      android:text="Music Name"
      android:textSize="17sp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
    <TextView
     android:id="@+id/data_album"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
     android:textColor="#bfe0e0e0"
     android:textSize="14sp"
     android:text="Music Artist"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I do this dynamically from java code? Can this be done using `set visibility` somehow? If yes, please explain new ways to do this are appreciated as well.

Comment: use `LayerDrawable` class: *"A Drawable that manages an array of other Drawables. These are drawn in array order, so the element with the largest index will be drawn on top."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can be done by using set visibility.  In your layout file, you will most likely need to use a Relative Layout so you can anchor both image views exactly the same.  Then on the view you do not want to initially display, you make it invisible by adding the following:

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

Then later on when you want to toggle the visibility on/off, you can use:

```
myImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
myImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `FrameLayout` here and place both `ImageView`s inside the `FrameLayout` and based on condition you can make one of them visible and other invisible

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="30dp"
>
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
android:layout_width="120dp"
android:layout_height="120dp"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:transitionName="albumArt"
android:id="@+id/album_art"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
android:src="@color/colorPrimary"/>

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView"
android:layout_width="120dp"
android:layout_height="120dp">
</ImageView>
</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
     android:id="@+id/data"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
      android:textColor="#ffffff"
      android:text="Music Name"
      android:textSize="17sp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
    <TextView
     android:id="@+id/data_album"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
     android:textColor="#bfe0e0e0"
     android:textSize="14sp"
     android:text="Music Artist"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```